# System.StackOverflowException in C# MVC with many variables in .cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a big `.cshtml` file in my project which has about 4000 lines of code (HTML and .NET variables). Until today everything worked fine but now I receive a `System.StackOverflowException` after I added some more variables.

After removing some lines again I realized that I must have reached a maximum of variables in a `cshtml` file.

I have reproduced the issue by using the ASP.NET template website which is automatically created when creating a new ASP.NET project. I have added the `@ViewBag.Title` line for about 5000 times and received again the `System.StackOverflowException`.

For me this Exception does not make any sense because the project should execute the lines one by one so that the stack will never have an overflow.

Do I miss something? Does anyone know how I can handle it except by inserting the data via JavaScript after it is sent to the user?

Comment: The error has been thrown because there are too many nested method calls, not because you have too many variables.

Comment: Yes sure, but I reproduced the issue by using the basic ASP.NET project without adding any function or function call. For me it seems to be that the variables are nested function calls in the .NET code but I hope someone can explain this behavior and give me a solution for it.

Comment: I have just reproduce this. After a very long page loading process the `System.StackOverflowException` is thrown from `App_Web_ufrc1vtb.dll` with empty (null) StackTrace. Suppose this is a bug in Razor renderer:\

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reproduce the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that this issue easily reproducible. Just create a new MVC5 project from default template and replace `Views/Home/Index.cshtml` with:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <span>@ViewBag.Title</span>
    @* ... *@
    @* ~ 5000 times of "<span>@ViewBag.Title</span>" *@
    @* ... *@
    <span>@ViewBag.Title</span>
</div>
```

Run your project and after some **loooong** loading process `System.StackOverflowException` is thrown from `App_Web_ufrc1vtb.dll` without StackTrace (`StackTrace == null`).

I advise you to open an issue on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack), however you can workaround this issue by reducing a size of your `.cshtml`. For example, I create a partial view `_PartView.cshtml` like this:

```
<div>
    <span>@ViewBag.Title</span>
    @* ... *@
    @* ~ 50 times of "<span>@ViewBag.Title</span>" *@
    @* ... *@
    <span>@ViewBag.Title</span>
</div>
```

Then I create another partial view `_PartOfPartsView.cshtml` like this:

```
<div>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PartView");}
    @* ... *@
    @* ~ 20 times of "@{Html.RenderPartial("_PartView");}" *@
    @* ... *@
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PartView");}
</div>
```

And finaly modify `Views/Home/Index.cshtml` like this:

```
<div class="row">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PartOfPartsView");}
    @* ... *@
    @* ~ 10 times of "@{Html.RenderPartial("_PartOfPartsView");}" *@
    @* ... *@
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PartOfPartsView");}
</div>
```

This is in total 10 000 times of `<span>@ViewBag.Title</span>` and all works fine.

Comment: I solved the problem by using this method) (y)